# How do I zip multiple lists inside a dictionary and find mean of them

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, zip, mean

How would I zip lists inside a dictionary:

```
somedict = {a: [1,2,3, b: [4,5,6], c: [7,8,9], d: [10,11,12]}
```

I want to zip all the values that are lists so it turns into this:

```
dlist = [[1,4,7,10], [2,5,8,11], [3,6,9,12]]
```

then add them so it becomes:

```
sumlist = [21, 26, 30]
```

then at the end find the sum by dividing by the length of each list:

```
meanlist = [5.25, 6.5, 7.5]
```

I was thinking maybe storing the lists in a numpy array and calling np.mean.

Comment: `zip` to zip and `sum` to sum.

Comment: What you have tried so far?  Your dictionaries are wrongly formatted. This comes when you haven't tried anything other than writing a question.

Comment: oh oops wrote the dictionary wrong I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works without using numpy

First we declare the dictionary

```py
somedict = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "c": [7, 8, 9], "d": [10, 11, 12]}
```

Then we zip each of the keys in the dictionary together to from the list of lists

```py
dlist = list(zip(somedict["a"], somedict["b"], somedict["c"], somedict["d"]))
```

Then we map sum over each of the sublists to create the list of sums

```py
sumlist = list(map(sum, dlist))
```

Here i use a lambda function to create an unamed function that calculates the mean of a list and map that over each of the sublists.

```py
meanlist = list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), dlist))
```

```py
print("dlist: {}".format(list(dlist)))
print("Sumlist: {}".format(sumlist))
print("meanList: {}".format(meanlist))

#Output:
#dlist: [(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
#Sumlist: [22, 26, 30]
#meanList: [5.5, 6.5, 7.5]
```